# Django Caching on front-end

Tags: django, caching

I was working with 2 applications that are within a DJango project: "customer" and "vendors". Each application has a HTML file named "testindex.html".

Whenever I typed:

> `http://myhost/customer/basic_info`

the correct page would show up

If I typed:

> `http://myhost/vendors/basic_info`

the page from `http://myhost/customer/basic_info` would show up

I found out that it was due to caching (since both applications use "testindex.html"). So again, "testindex.html" is caching.

How can one get around this problem?

TIA

Details are listed below. I have the following views defined:

***urls.py for the project***

```
urlpatterns = [

... snip ...

url(r'^customer/', include('libmstr.customer.urls')),
url(r'^vendors/', include('libmstr.vendors.urls')),
]
```

***views.py for customer***

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def basic_info(request):
    return render(request, 'testindex.html', {})
```

***views.py for vendors***

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def basic_info(request):
    return render(request, 'testindex.html', {})
```

***urls.py for customers***

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

# list of templates
app_name = 'customer'

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^basic_info/$', views.basic_info, name='basic_info'),
]
```

***urls.py for vendors***

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

# list of templates
app_name = 'vendors'

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^basic_info/$', views.basic_info, name='basic_info'),
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have two templates, `customers/templates/testindex.html` and `vendors/templates/testindex.html`.

When you call `render(request, 'testindex.html', {})`, the app directories template loader searches the templates directory for each app in `INSTALLED_APPS`, and stops the first time it finds a match. If `customers` is above `vendors` in `INSTALLED_APPS`, then it will always use the customers template.

For this reason, Django recommends that you name your templates `customers/templates/customers/testindex.html` and `vendors/templates/vendors/testindex.html`, and change your views to use `customers/testindex.html` and `vendors/testindex.html`. This way you avoid clashes.

Comment: Thanks - following your suggestion resolved the problem :-)